# COALESCE in MySQL returning conversion failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute coalesce as nvl in oracle.

```
SELECT COALESCE('SYSTEM ADMIN',10)
```

ideally it should return "SYSTEM ADMIN" AS OUTPUT.

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL,10)
```

And this should return 10.

but this syntax is returning....

```
SELECT COALESCE('SYSTEM ADMIN',10)
```

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SYSTEM ADMIN' to data type int.

plz help what's wrong here

Comment: All arguments should be of the same type.

Comment: this is not `MySQL` right? it's an error message from `SQL Server`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also return a string alternative, (*must have the same data type*)

```
SELECT COALESCE('SYSTEM ADMIN', '10') FROM ....
```

Comment: the reason why you are not getting an error in mysql server is because it silently cast the data type.